# create module for vtiger

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

i want to create a module and develop it in vtiger so i created a file that contains some script . i found this somewhere and i used it . supposedly it works and makes table and after running if you run script again you gave this error `Module already present - choose a different name` . my issue is there is no folder related to new module and also no module in tools sub menu ! and if i want to update it for example add any field or change something . how to do it?

this is my file that is in root of vtiger:

```
<?php
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';

$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

$MODULENAME = 'namava';

$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);
if ($moduleInstance || file_exists('modules/'.$MODULENAME)) {
    echo "Module already present - choose a different name.";
} else {
    $moduleInstance = new Vtiger_Module();
    $moduleInstance->name = $MODULENAME;
    $moduleInstance->parent = 'Tools';
    $moduleInstance->save();

    // Schema Setup
    $moduleInstance->initTables();

    // Field Setup
    $block = new Vtiger_Block();
    $block->label = 'LBL_' . strtoupper($moduleInstance->name) . '_INFORMATION';
    $moduleInstance->addBlock($block);

    $blockcf = new Vtiger_Block();
    $blockcf->label = 'LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION';
    $moduleInstance->addBlock($blockcf);

    $field1 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field1->name = 'summary';
    $field1->label = 'Summary';
    $field1->uitype = 2;
    $field1->column = $field1->name;
    $field1->columntype = 'VARCHAR(255)';
    $field1->typeofdata = 'V~M';
    $block->addField($field1);

    $moduleInstance->setEntityIdentifier($field1);

    $field2 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field2->name = 'film';
    $field2->label = 'film On';
    $field2->uitype = 5;
    $field2->column = $field2->name;
    $field2->columntype = 'Date';
    $field2->typeofdata = 'D~O';
    $block->addField($field2);

    $field3 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field3->name = 'actor';
    $field3->label = 'actor on';
    $field3->uitype = 71;
    $field3->column = $field3->name;
    $field3->columntype = 'VARCHAR(255)';
    $field3->typeofdata = 'V~M';
    $block->addField($field3);

    $field3 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $field3->name = 'description';
    $field3->label = 'Description';
    $field3->uitype = 19;
    $field3->column = 'description';
    $field3->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $blockcf->addField($field3);

    // Recommended common fields every Entity module should have (linked to core table)
    $mfield1 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $mfield1->name = 'assigned_user_id';
    $mfield1->label = 'Assigned To';
    $mfield1->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $mfield1->column = 'smownerid';
    $mfield1->uitype = 53;
    $mfield1->typeofdata = 'V~M';
    $block->addField($mfield1);

    $mfield2 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $mfield2->name = 'CreatedTime';
    $mfield2->label = 'Created Time';
    $mfield2->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $mfield2->column = 'createdtime';
    $mfield2->uitype = 70;
    $mfield2->typeofdata = 'T~O';
    $mfield2->displaytype = 2;
    $block->addField($mfield2);

    $mfield3 = new Vtiger_Field();
    $mfield3->name = 'ModifiedTime';
    $mfield3->label = 'Modified Time';
    $mfield3->table = 'vtiger_crmentity';
    $mfield3->column = 'modifiedtime';
    $mfield3->uitype = 70;
    $mfield3->typeofdata = 'T~O';
    $mfield3->displaytype = 2;
    $block->addField($mfield3);

    // Filter Setup
    $filter1 = new Vtiger_Filter();
    $filter1->name = 'All';
    $filter1->isdefault = true;
    $moduleInstance->addFilter($filter1);
    $filter1->addField($field1)->addField($field2, 1)->addField($field3, 2)->addField($mfield1, 3);

    // Sharing Access Setup
    $moduleInstance->setDefaultSharing();
}
```

i also used another way for create skeleton of module with
`php vtlib/tools/console.php` but my issue is it creates just one field and i dont know how to add more field in code with this way

could you please tell me how to do it in standard way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Error: Module already present - choose a different name

> This means you have already executed your script or you are trying to create a module with an existing module name. Look at the if condition in your script file.

2. Add new fields

> In case you are still looking to add more fields then you need to remove that if condition and also this block of code.

```
// Add a New module, and remove these 4 lines once the script is executed and the module exists in the vtiger_tab table.

$moduleInstance = new Vtiger_Module();
$moduleInstance->name = $MODULENAME;
$moduleInstance->parent = 'Tools';
$moduleInstance->save();

// This line creates new tables for your module
// 1. vtiger_modulename
// 2. vtiger_modulenamecf

$moduleInstance->initTables();

// This code block adds a new Block and adds an entry in vtiger_blocks. If it does not exist then you can re-execute else remove it from a script.

$block = new Vtiger_Block();
$block->label = 'LBL_' . strtoupper($moduleInstance->name) . '_INFORMATION';
$moduleInstance->addBlock($block);
```

3. Add a module in the Menu

> Add this line in your script to add the Module name in the Menu

```
Settings_MenuEditor_Module_Model::addModuleToApp($moduleInstance->name, $moduleInstance->parent);
```